# How to get an un-parameterized type from an parameterized generic type?

Tags: c#, generics

Is there a way to take a parameterized generic type and get the corresponding un-parameterized type?

```
Type parameterizedFoo = typeof(Foo<double>);
Type unparameterizedFoo = parameterizedFoo.TypeWithoutParameters; // == typeof(Foo<>);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Type unparameterizedFoo = parameterizedFoo.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
```

Comment: Note that `GetGenericTypeDefinition` throws on non-generic types, so depending on where and how you use it, you may want/need to check `IsGenericType` first.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [`GetGenericTypeDefinition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition.aspx) method.

```
Type parameterizedFoo = typeof(Foo<double>);
Type unparameterizedFoo = parameterizedFoo.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
Console.WriteLine(unparameterizedFoo == typeof(Foo<>)); // True
```